# Flutter Null Safety Migration - StreamBuilder snapshot - Cannot access length or data through index

Tags: flutter

i'm trying to migrate to null safety.
I'm currently stuck with StreamBuilder and ListView.builder.
I'm unsure how to adjust the code, that the itemCount and an element from the snapshot data can be safely accessed.

Is there a way to cast Object to int?

Errors

- `The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int?'.`
- `The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.`

The code is a minimal version, where I want to display List elements

```
class _ListState extends State<List> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final database = Provider.of<AppDatabase>(context);

    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: database.XYZ(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {

        if (snapshot.data != null) {
          return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                return ListItem(snapshot.data[index]);
              }
          );
        } else {
          return Text("No data");
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Possible Solution - Specify StreamBuilder with Class

```
class _ListState extends State<List> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final database = Provider.of<AppDatabase>(context);

    return StreamBuilder<List<Element>>(
      stream: database.XYZ(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {

        if (snapshot.data != null) {
          return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                return ListItem(snapshot.data[index]);
              }
          );
        } else {
          return Text("No data");
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: add type to your stream builder. StreamBuilder<type>()

Comment: Thank you for the fast response, i added the solution

Answer (score 3):

You can solve it in two ways:

1. Provide a specific type to your `StreamBuilder`

   ```dart
   StreamBuilder<List> (...)
   ```
2. Use `as` to downcast.

   ```dart
   builder: (context, snapshot) {
     if (snapshot.data != null) {
       final list = snapshot.data as List; // <-- Downcasting

       return ListView.builder(
         itemCount: list.length, // Works now
        );
     } else {
       return Text("No data");
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: I was about to write the solution using `T` but then I saw someone mentioned that in the comment, so I wrote another way of doing it.